# how to add duration time on google map draw path?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I able to draw path from source to destination it's working fine. but now I looking add to duration on path like google or ubar. tried but my duration marker little  bit away from drawer path.

```
let path = GMSPath(fromEncodedPath:objMapModel.arrayMapPath[0].routes.first?.overviewPolyline.points ?? "")
let rectangle = GMSPolyline(path: path)
rectangle.strokeWidth = 5.0
marker.map = mapView
rectangle.map = mapView
```

I am looking something like this image. I want to add marker on path with duration time`(ex 27h)`

[here is image more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04V4Y.png)

Answer (score 0):

The duration time is also given by google API response and the parameter is like this and it's call  **estimated time**.

```
       "duration" : {
          "text" : "27 mins",
          "value" : 1615
         },
```

Comment: I don't think that is what he was asking. He said he needed the `marker` like thing shown in the image placed near the `route`.

Comment: Sorry may be i'm not on track.
But can do this marker.snippet = //your time and then you will call it in didupdatelocation.

Answer (score 0):

Create your customMarker view and you use to markerInfowindow. plz try it.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {

    //Create customMarker and retur UIView
    return customMarker

}
OR
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoContents marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView?
{
  let placeMarker = marker as! PlaceMarker
  let view = UIView(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 150))
  if let markerView = UIView.viewFromNibName(name: "MarkerView") as? MarkerView 
  {
    infoView.nameLabel.text = placeMarker.name
    view.addSubview(markerView!)
    return view
   } else {
    return nil
  }
}
```